# Postgresql 11 Create or Replace Procedure GetMultipleResultSets(INOUT ref1 refcursor, INOUT ref2 refcursor); Automatic cursor deferencing using Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Requirement:
How to get back the multiple refcursor data from a postgresql 11 procedure (not a function) without using the fetch statement using npgsql 4.0 from ado.net.

Here is the sample which i have tried:

Postgresql Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.GetMultipleResultSets(
    INOUT ref1 refcursor,
    INOUT ref2 refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
begin
    open ref1 for
    select * from public."tblTestTable1";

    open ref2 for
    select * from public."tblTestTable2";   
end;
$BODY$;
```

C# Code using Npgsql 4.0:

```
    public DataSet ReturnAsDataSet(string procedureName)
    {
        this.dataSet = new DataSet();   

        OpenConnection();
        NpgsqlTransaction objTransaction = this.Connection.BeginTransaction();

        NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        NpgsqlCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand();

        try
        {
            NpgsqlParameter refCursorParam1 = new NpgsqlParameter("@ref1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
            refCursorParam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            refCursorParam1.Value = "ref1";
            command.Parameters.Add(refCursorParam1);  

            refCursorParam2 = new NpgsqlParameter("@ref2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
            refCursorParam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            refCursorParam2.Value = "ref2";
            command.Parameters.Add(refCursorParam2);

            command.CommandText = "call " + procedureName + "(@ref1, @ref2)";               
            command.Transaction = objTransaction;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);          

            objTransaction.Commit();                

        }

        catch (NpgsqlException ex)
        {       
            if (objTransaction != null)                
                objTransaction.Rollback();                

            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
            command.Dispose();
            objTransaction.Dispose();
        }

        return this.dataSet;
    }
```

This code will return a table having the "ref1", "ref2" as the columns and "ref1" and "ref2" as the values inside it as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x7TI.jpg)

But I need the actual result sets returned from the procedure.
How can I achieve it without manually fetching those refcursor data. 
I mean without using "fetch all ref" statement how can we retrieve the data by executing either `ExecuteReader()` or adapter.`Fill()` methods as above.
Is there any automatic cursor dereferencing available in npgsql?

Please provide the answer if anyone knows.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not done for you by Npgsql, [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1785) tracks it. You can see [this long discussions on the pros and cons of this](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/438). At the moment you'll have to call FETCH on the cursors yourself.

Comment: Hi Shay, thanks for your immediate response. I have gone through those links you have given here. Ok, let me use the "Fetch" statement then. Thank you.